# Best method to solve this PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I need to solve this Partial Differential Equation for $\lambda(x,y)$,

$$\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial x} + h(x,y)\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial y} - \lambda \frac{\partial h}{\partial y} = 0$$ 
where $$\frac{dy}{dx} = h(x,y).$$

The additional information given is $\lambda$ is a bivariate polynomial in $x$ and $y$. My initial approach was to try using the method of characteristics, but I know I can't since $y$ is dependent on $x$.

So I guess I should use some sort of degree bound, and find the coefficients by equating powers on both sides, However I just wanted to know if there is actually a better method to do this before I proceed?

Thanks