# Method of characteristics - a general doubt.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

This is a continuation of my previous unanswered question [Best method to solve this PDE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422962/best-method-to-solve-this-pde)

I understand that the method of characteristics, cannot be used for more than one dependent variable from here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics, that is

$$ a(x,y)*\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + b(x,y)*\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
+ c(x,y)*u(x,y) = 0$$

$y$ is independent of $x$

However when we write $$\frac{dx}{da(x,y)} = \frac{dy}{db(x,y)}$$ , doesn't it imply that $y$ is dependent on $x$, i.e y $y$ can be written as a function of $x$